# Real time processing program appends new data from Keithley Digital Multimeter to csv file without overwriting data

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, real-time, measurement

### Current code for this project:

```
>>> import py2700 as DMM
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> my_multimeter = DMM.Multimeter('TCPIP::169.254.69.212::1394::SOCKET')
>>> time.sleep(5)
>>> my_multimeter.set_temperature_units('C')
>>> my_multimeter.set_timeout(100000)
>>> my_multimeter.define_channels([101,102,103,104,105],
              DMM.MeasurementType.resistance())
>>> my_multimeter.setup_scan()
>>> result = my_multimeter.scan(time.time_ns()/(10**9))
>>> print(my_multimeter.make_csv_header())
Channel 101 Time (s),Channel 101 Value (Ohms),Channel 102 Time (s),Channel 102 Value (Ohms),Channel 103 Time (s),Channel 103 Value (Ohms),Channel 104 Time (s),Channel 104 Value (Ohms),Channel 105 Time (s),Channel 105 Value (Ohms)

>>> type(my_multimeter.make_csv_header())
<class 'str'>
>>> print(result.make_csv_row())
1614183965.0267806,19.7630787,1614183965.3737216,19.82827,1614183965.7207227,19.8339138,1614183966.0677166,19.8570061,1614183966.4147205,19.8999825

>>> type(result.make_csv_row())
<class 'str'>
>>> result
<py2700.Multimeter.ScanResult object at 0x11708DC0>
>>> print(result)
['+1.97630787E+01OHM', '+0.000000SECS', '+00000RDNG#', '+1.98282700E+01OHM', '+0.346941SECS', '+00001RDNG#', '+1.98339138E+01OHM', '+0.693942SECS', '+00002RDNG#', '+1.98570061E+01OHM', '+1.040936SECS', '+00003RDNG#', '+1.98999825E+01OHM', '+1.387940SECS', '+00004RDNG#']



>>> list1= result.make_csv_row()
>>> list1
'1614183965.0267806,19.7630787,1614183965.3737216,19.82827,1614183965.7207227,19.8339138,1614183966.0677166,19.8570061,1614183966.4147205,19.8999825\n'

>>> list1[0::2]
'11136.270,9737711136.771,988711136.272,9831811136.676,9870111136.170,98985'
>>> print(list1)
1614183965.0267806,19.7630787,1614183965.3737216,19.82827,1614183965.7207227,19.8339138,1614183966.0677166,19.8570061,1614183966.4147205,19.8999825

>>> type(list1)
<class 'str'>
>>> channel1=list1[19:28]

>>> print(channel1)
19.763078


>>> with open("random.csv", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(channel1)
```

---

*Example of desired output: Resistance data is collected every minute from the sample*

```
             Channel 1| Channel 2| channel 3| channel 4| Channel 5
```

Measurement 1  |    9.53  |  10.53   |   13.91    |    9.67   |   9.13
Measurement 2  |    9.56  |  10.55   |   13.92    |    9.61   |   9.15

Measurement 3  | 9.72  |  10.96   |   13.94    |   9.68   |  9.12

Measurement 4  | 9.89  |  10.56   |   13.93    |   9.65   |  9.11

Measurement 5  |     #    |     #    |      #     |       #   |      #

Ignore the timestamps, I just want the new resistance measurement every minute.

Answer (score 0):

If the main problem is that the code overwrites the data each time, then you should use the mode "a" instead of "w" when using open, like this:

```
with open("random.csv", "a") as fp:
    fp.write(channel1)
```

"a" stands for append, while "w" stands for write and it will always overwrite the whole file. Then if you want to take continuous measurements you should run the script periodically with some powershell or bash commands, although a simpler way would be to just put the main parts of the code that you want to continuosly run in a while loop like this:

```
#import libraries

while True:
    # take the measurements
    # format the data
    # save the new measurements
    with open("random.csv", "a") as fp:
        fp.write(channel1)
    #time.sleep(5)
```

and now when you run the script it will take the measurement roughly every 5 seconds (depending on how much time your processing takes) until you stop the program.

**EDIT**
to convert your string to a list:

```
real_list = list1.split(',')
```

then you need to format your output, if you want to use the pipe symbol:

```
string_to_append = " | ".join(real_list)
```

And you would use this string_to_append variable here:

```
with open("random.csv", "a") as fp:
    fp.write(string_to_append)
```

this will write a single line where each measurement is separated by " | " symbol, you can change that to whatever you want.

I also see you imported pandas but didnt use it so I would also suggest to look into that, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is really helpful when working with tabular data, csv files, etc, it might make writing and formatting output easier and theres loads of information on how to use pandas on stack overflow.

Comment: I tried the append method you mentioned; it does add the value, but it adds the value to the same cell. I want each measurement placed in the same row but different columns. Once a new measurement happens I want the same thing to happen. Channel 1, measurement 2 in the Column A2, Channel2, measurement 2 in column b2 etc.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, since you are saving this as a csv the problem you mention might be have to do with the character to use as a separator. The measurement as I understand returns the values separated by a comma which is standard for csv(comma separated values), however if you want to you can always separate it by another character such as the pipe "|" with the help of a for loop. However I think you are facing another problem - you list1 variable is not a list, but rather a string so you need to convert it, I will update my answer on how to do that.